# How to resolve gradle dependency conflicts on library root dependency?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, dependencies, retrofit

In my project I have two dependencies with okio as a transitive dependency conflict. In theory, gradle should solve it by choosing the highest version, but that didn't work.

I have been trying everything, since exclude until force the version from okio lib, but nothing works. Looking on external libraries path, I realized that one of the dependencies contains the okio as a path of the dependency, and I believe that this is the problem. But how can I solve this?

This is a simple gradle example with my two dependencies. Commented lines are my failed attempts to solve the problem:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.72'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

//configurations.all {
//    resolutionStrategy.force('com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3')
//}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"

    // -> dependency one
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2"
//    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2"){
//        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okio'
//    }

    // -> dependency two
    implementation "com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.18"
//    implementation ("com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.18") {
//        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okio'
//    }

//    implementation "com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3"

//    implementation "com.squareup.okio:okio"
//    constraints {
//        implementation("com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3") {
//            because 'transitive version conflict'
//        }
//    }
}
```

To get the error, just have a Main.kt file with the code:

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder()
}
```

And the error obtained is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean okio.ByteString.startsWith(okio.ByteString)'
    at okio.Options.of(Options.java:64)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:73)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.java:124)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:449)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:4)
```

And finally, this is the library root that I mentioned from dependence with the included okio

[image]

I will be very grateful if you can help me.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that the only solution is to separate the app into modules, placing each dependency in a different module. Even though I was reluctant it was the only way I found.